# SQL JOIN Master group to Result group

Tags: sql, postgresql, excel, vba

I am using Excel VBA and connecting to PGSQL using OleDB. I have 2 lines of SQL code that work fine on there own, but I now need to merge them.
The 1st query is the master group that finds the people I need for the 2nd query

```
Const sqlconnection = "Provider=oledb;"

Dim conn As New Connection
conn.ConnectionString = sqlconnection
conn.Open
Dim rs As Recordset

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A1").Select

Dim GRP As String
GRP = "SELECT h.master_id, p.surname, p.forename1, h.eventdate, h.code " _
& "FROM hist h INNER JOIN person p ON h.master_id=p.entity_id " _
& "AND code LIKE 'C10%' " _
& "ORDER BY h.master_id "
```

The 2nd query needs to show the results based on the 1st group of people it found.

```
Dim DATA As String
DATA = "SELECT latest.master_id, p.surname, p.forename1, " _
& "SUBSTRING(latestAP,1,10) eventdate, " _
& "SUBSTRING(latestAP,12,3) TX1, " _
& "SUBSTRING(latestAP,16,3) TX2 " _
& "FROM ( " _
& "SELECT master_id, " _
& "MAX(CAST(eventdate AS VARCHAR(10)) + '.' + RIGHT('00' + TEXT1,3)+ '.' + RIGHT('00' + TEXT2,3)) as latestAP " _
& "FROM ap " _
& "GROUP BY master_id) AS latest " _
& "LEFT JOIN person p ON latest.master_id = p.entity_id " _
& "ORDER BY master_id "

Set rs = conn.Execute(DATA)
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=rs, Destination:=Range("A1"))
    .Refresh
End With

rs.Close
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider adding first query as an additional derived table to second query:

```
Dim DATA As String 
DATA = "SELECT latest.master_id, p.surname, p.forename1, " _ 
     & "       SUBSTRING(latestAP,1,10) eventdate, " _ 
     & "       SUBSTRING(latestAP,12,3) TX1, " _ 
     & "       SUBSTRING(latestAP,16,3) TX2 " _ 
     & "FROM ( " _ 
     & "      SELECT master_id, " _ 
     & "             MAX(CAST(eventdate AS VARCHAR(10)) + '.' + " _
     & "                 RIGHT('00' + TEXT1,3) + '.' + " _
     & "                 RIGHT('00' + TEXT2,3)) as latestAP " _ 
     & "      FROM ap " _ 
     & "      GROUP BY master_id) AS latest " _ 
     & "INNER JOIN ( " _
     & "      SELECT h.master_id, p.surname, p.forename1, "_
     & "             h.eventdate, h.code " _ 
     & "      FROM hist h " _
     & "      INNER JOIN person p ON h.master_id=p.entity_id " _ 
     & "      AND code LIKE 'C10%') AS grp "
     & "ON grp.master_id = latest.master_id" 
     & "LEFT JOIN person p ON latest.master_id = p.entity_id " _ 
     & "ORDER BY master_id "
```

Comment: This is wonderful thank you. However I keep getting a runtime error "missing FROM-clause entry for table "h"; SQLSTATE 42P01

Comment: I got this working now from your code, so thank you very much. I removed the h. references and it worked great. Thank you so much

Comment: Great to hear! Interesting, h references might be due to a needed `AS h` for table alias but the p references did not fail.